# dart freezed convert to another data type

Tags: flutter, dart, freezed, flutter-freezed

`@JsonKey(name: "favourite") @Default("") String favourite`

In my json `favourite` is rather `Y` and `N` , which mean `true` or `false`, possible to convert directly in freezed? So I can directly use boolean, instead of String

Answer (score 4):

You can create a custom converter for the field.

```dart
class MyConverter implements JsonConverter<String, bool> {
  const MyConverter ();

  @override
  MyResponse fromJson(string input) {
    switch (input) {
      case "Y": return true;
      case "N": return false;
      default: throw NotSupportedError();
    }
  }

  @override
  String toJson(bool input) {
    switch (input) {
      case true: return "Y";
      case false: return "N";
      default: throw NotSupportedError();
    }
  }
}
```

```dart
@JsonKey(name: "favourite") @Default("") @MyConverter() String favourite
```

Comment: still have to use String or can be `@JsonKey(name: "favourite") @Default(false) @MyConverter() boolean favourite` ?

Comment: Hi, I followed your suggestion and I getting `'StringBoolConverter.fromJson' ('ProductItem Function(String)') isn't a valid override of 'JsonConverter.fromJson' ('String Function(bool)').`

Comment: @FeelRightz What is `ProductItem`? You never mentioned that type in your question.